# Passing a promise to a callback

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to write a javascript function that will show a bootstrap modal dialog and create a callback that will be executed when the dialog is close.  This is all within a Knockout view model, but not sure that's important.

```
self.showModalDialog = function(optionData){
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    self.modalDlgViewModel.data = optionData;
    $('#myDialog').on('hidden.bs.modal',
        function (deferred) {
            deferred.resolve(self.modalDlgViewModel.status);
        });
    self.showDialog(true);
    return deferred;
}
```

This seems like it should work, but it when its gets to the the line of code inside the call back, deferred.resolve is no longer defined. What's going on with my promise?

Thanks

Comment: You declared "deferred" as a variable but then re-scoped it by defining it as the function param name?

Comment: The callback function of the `'hidden.bs.modal'` event, containing the event object, so you're overriding the `deferred` object - it's actually the event object inside the callback function. So change  `function (deferred) {` to `function (e) {` and it might start working

Comment: also change `$('#myDialog').on('hidden.bs.modal',` to `$('#myDialog').one('hidden.bs.modal',` so this event trigger only once and for every deferred object you're passing when opening the modal

Comment: Thanks!  That solved it